# Restart application no longer working with Cap 3.1 and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, capistrano3

The following task was working before we upgraded to Rails 4 and Cap 3.1

```
desc 'Restart application'
task :restart do
  on roles(:web), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
    execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
  end
end
```

First of all, I know Cap 3.1 doesn't implicitly call :restart anymore so I added the following:

```
after :publishing, :restart
```

However, it fails on attempting to 'touch' the restart.txt file so that Apache will reload the application.

```
cap aborted!
touch stdout: Nothing written
touch stderr: Nothing written
config/deploy.rb:46:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
config/deploy.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:restart
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Command::Failed: touch stdout: Nothing written
touch stderr: Nothing written
>
```

Do I still need a restart?  It generally seems okay but I'm wondering if there could be issues that come up by not finding a way to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Had a similar issue, tried to run this command on server and got an error
`touch: cannot touch 'myappdir/releases/20140416074158/tmp/restart.txt': No such file or directory`, so I simply added a line to create a `release_path/tmp` dir:

```ruby
desc 'Restart application'
task :restart do
  on roles(:web), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
    execute :mkdir, '-p', "#{ release_path }/tmp"
    execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I'll check this out ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

What's the error message for the failure?

This works for me:

```
namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app, :web), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end
end

after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
```

Comment: How do I go verbose with cap?  Not much of value in the error message.

Comment: Yeah, cap -v didn't give me much more.  Already have loglevel set to DEBUG.

Comment: Pretty sure the suggestion is syntactically identical to mine.  Usage of explicit 'deploy:...' is same as ':...' as far as I understand it.

Comment: Probably.  Just wanted to show that you might have other problems as the above does work.  Weird cap won't give you more error info.

Answer (score 2):

I've modified the given answer to show **the solution that has worked for me**.

I've just enter the next lines at the end of the `config/deploy.rb` file.

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:web), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :mkdir, '-p', "#{ release_path }/tmp"
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :deploy, "deploy:restart"
  after :rollback, "deploy:restart"
end
```

Doing that, Passenger will restart automatically after each deploy/rollback.

I think it worth mentioning that you can also restart Passenger manually from your **development environment** each time you run the next line:

```
cap production deploy:restart
```

Answer (score 0):

On my cap I got a similar error on a multi-server deploy.  It seems that the problem is that it is relying on your running a previous rails command (to generate the tmp directory) before restarting, such as db:migrate.