# Capistrano 3 Deployment Initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I deploy Rails app so infrequently that I always get into a head-butting contest with Capistrano when I do it. Here, I have a repo on Github. I'm using Capistrano 3.2.1 and the relevant (i.e., non-boilerplate) part of my `deploy.rb` is this:

```
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, 'my_app'
set :scm, :git
set :repository, "git@github.com:my_github_user/my_app.git"


set :user, 'deploy'
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/rails_apps/my_app"
```

in `config/deploy/production.rb` I have this:

```
role :app, %w{deploy@my_domain.com}
role :web, %w{deploy@my_domain.com}
role :db,  %w{deploy@my_domain.com}
```

I get hung up on the following error:

```
DEBUG[03378c05] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h  on my_domain.com
DEBUG[03378c05] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/my_app/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h  )
DEBUG[03378c05]     usage: git ls-remote [--heads] [--tags]  [-u <exec> | --upload-pack <exec>] <repository> <refs>...
DEBUG[03378c05] Finished in 0.165 seconds with exit status 129 (failed).
```

Note also that I am repeating strings like `my_app`. I used to be able to do:

```
set :repository, "git@github.com:my_github_user/#{application}.git"
```

but now I get an error that the property or method `application` is not found.

I know I am missing a step or steps. I have simply been unable to figure out what these steps are.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `set :repository, "git@github.com:my_github_user/#{fetch(:application)}.git"`.

Comment: That solves the interpolation issue, Thanks. (One step back in syntax vinegar, IMO), but not the failure in git ls-remote. Any clues on that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. Told you I always butt heads with Capistrano!

The `:repository` variable was changed to `:repo_url` (d'oh).

Using `fetch` as mentioned above works.

You also need to add a line to your restart script as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489712/restart-application-no-longer-working-with-cap-3-1-and-rails-4):

```
task :restart do
  on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
    # Your restart mechanism here, for calicowebdev:

    execute :mkdir, '-p', "#{ release_path }/tmp"
```

The `mkdir` part is what you need to add.